# PHP. Why return in included file dosen't assign with variable?

Tags: php, include, return

For example i have 2 file:

```
//db.php
return array(
   'server'=>'localhost',
   'db'=>'mydb',
   'name'=>'root',
   'password'=>'root',
);
```

and second file:

```
//index.php
$config = (include 'db.php');
```

After that `$config = 1` if file included or `$config = 0` if file not included, but `$config` must be `array()` in `db.php` file.

What a problem?

windows 7x64, apache 2.2, php 5.4

Comment: look http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, Example #5 include and the return statement

Comment: i know, what i can use function, but this is not mine project, and he has that code, and that code work on server but doesn't work on my localhost...

Comment: There's no obvious reason why it shouldn't work. Make sure that you're including the correct file, that there isn't another file with the same name elsewhere in the path that could be the one actually being included instead

Comment: Easiest way to do what @Mark suggests: `echo 'This is the correct file!'` in `db.php`.

Comment: im sure included this file, because, i forgot say, when I open localhost in browser, he displayed array() that return in included file, and var_dump($config) is "int 1"

Comment: What do you mean "he displayed array()".... the code you've posted doesn't actually display anything..... do you have a `<?php` at the top of your `db.php` file?

Comment: look this please http://prntscr.com/6r26p5

Comment: **SHORT OPEN TAG!!! `<?`** The array is not supposed to be output at all; if it is, something's wrong with your file. In this case, PHP isn't configured to handle short open tags.

Comment: thanks, now working, i know what that is simply problem)) maybe you add answer and i mark him as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

true answer from [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)
SHORT OPEN TAG!!! `<? The array is not supposed to be output at all; if it is, something's wrong with your file. In this case, PHP isn't configured to handle short open tags`

Answer (score 0):

You can use INI file for your DB credentials. Don't forget to deny access to config.ini in .htaccess file.

**config.ini**

```
[database]
server = localhost
db = mydb
name = root
password = root
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

    // Access to credentials
    echo $config['server'];
?>
```

Comment: how I say before, that not mine project, i do him with other developers and we use VCS. I don't want change core code for load config.

Comment: While, yes, true, but it doesn't answer the question.